# Writing long / multiline macro

Tags: macros, haxe

I'm writing some macro and this is the sample code

```
macro public static function test(object:Expr,name:Expr):Expr{
    #if debug
    return macro if ($object.get($name) == true) {$object.scan();$object.submit();return;};
    #else   
    return macro trace("debug mode only");
    #end
}
```

As my macro getting longer & complex, I'm thinking there must be another way to write multi-line macro other than joining statement with semicolon.

any suggestion on writing multi-line (approx. 50-100 generated line) macro ?

Comment: What problem did you actually encounter when you tried adding line breaks? Expression reification should support any valid _expression_ regardless of line breaks, since they don't matter at all in the Haxe syntax.

Comment: Try it.  You can have 50-100 lines in expression reification no worries.  You can even do whole classes.

Comment: thanks both of you. I found answers from both of your hints :D 

i'll post the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/MarcWeber/haxe-macro-examples/blob/master/Macro.hx) example, I found out that you can return a block of expression, not just one line. Simply add the statement inside a curly bracket and return it. You can also [return a class](http://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-class.html) using macro.

```
macro public static function test(object:Expr, name:Expr):Expr {
#if debug
    return macro
        if ($object.get($name) == true) {
            $object.scan();
            $object.submit();
            return;
        }
#else   
    return macro {
        trace("not working!")
        trace("compile with -Ddebug");
    }
#end
}
```